# MySQL tables_priv corrupted

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a mysql database and i need to create an user for the login.
This user need the privileges to only select on only one table where the login info are.
on phpmyadmin when i use the gui i receive this error:

'#1194 - the table 'tables_priv' is signed as corrupted and need to be repaired.
If i use the cli with this command:
'''
GRANT SELECT ON dbname.tblname to 'dbuser'
'''
i receve the seme error.

the database exist. the table exist. the user exit. i have root access.

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. Ideally, you should provide some code, to help the community help you.

Comment: run reoair table before hand https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/repair-table.html

Answer (score 0):

"Repair" the table:

Plan A (assuming you can connect as root):  `CHECK TABLE mysql.tables_priv;`  That will probably tell that it needs repairing.  Then do `REPAIR TABLE mysql.tables_priv;`

Plan B: See how to do the equivalent with `myisamchk` from the shell prompt.